# Parsing names with commas from email module's `parseaddr`

Tags: python, email-validation

`email.utils.parseaddr` doesn't seem to be able to handle cases where the name is listed in *lastname, firstname* format (a format that is common in email metadata).

Example:

```
>>> import email.utils

>>> email.utils.parseaddr('Joe A. Smith <smithja@yahoo.com>')  # OK
('Joe A. Smith', 'smithja@yahoo.com')

>>> email.utils.parseaddr('Smith, Joe A. <smithja@yahoo.com>')  # Fails
('', 'Smith')
```

Is this intentionally designed?  `email` purports to follow RFC [2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).  The spec for the full string is defined as

```
angle-addr      =       [CFWS] "<" addr-spec ">" [CFWS] / obs-angle-addr
```

But's its unclear to me what can constitute "CFWS."  Is the return type `('', 'Smith')` compliant with the RFC?

---

Version info:

```
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As defined in section 3.2.3 of the RFC, `CFWS` is whitespace & comments, so it does not apply here.  You want to look at the following definitions, scattered throughout the grammar:

```
name-addr       =       [display-name] angle-addr
display-name    =       phrase
phrase          =       1*word / obs-phrase
word            =       atom / quoted-string
atom            =       [CFWS] 1*atext [CFWS]
atext           = [a bunch of characters not including comma]
obs-phrase      =       word *(word / "." / CFWS)
```

From this, we can see that `'Joe A. Smith <smithja@yahoo.com>'` is valid because `Joe A. Smith` is an `obs-phrase`, but `'Smith, Joe A. <smithja@yahoo.com>'` is not valid because commas aren't allowed in an `atom` or `obs-phrase`.  Instead, you must use a `quoted-string`:

```
>>> email.utils.parseaddr('"Smith, Joe A." <smithja@yahoo.com>')
('Smith, Joe A.', 'smithja@yahoo.com')
```